# How to pick the latest time value of a date in a listview time column

Tags: c#

I am working on c# form. I have a listview control, a button, and a textfield. I would like to scan the listview with a button click to pick the lastest time value in a column with series of different values (in the picture 22:02 is the latest time value)...

[image]

Comment: What have you tried ? Including your code would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
string[] myArray = YourListBox.Items;
Array.Sort(myArray);
string latestTime = myArray[myArray.Length - 1];
```

Try this (I did this from my phone so it can contains some mistakes...

Comment: Thank you very much.. I havent tried it yet but it looks very good